# Why not use a while loop for FIZZBUZZ in C?

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Only been coding in C for about a month, but wondered why the while loop wasn't used more often for FIZZBUZZ.  Is it not as clean or some other reason?  Here's what I came up with:

```
int main()
{
    int num=1;
    while(num<=100)
    {
        if (num%3==0 && num%5==0)
        {
            printf("FIZZBUZZ!!!\n");
        }
        else if (num%3==0)
        {
            printf("FIZZ!!!\n");
        }
        else if (num%5==0)
        {
            printf("BUZZ!!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        num++;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: And what is the problem? Why do you think this is any better (or worse) than any other solution?

Comment: Because a for loop looks cleaner that's all.

Comment: BTW, you might want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com for stuff like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop can be neatly folded into a `for` loop:

```
for(int num = 1; num <= 100; ++num)
```

There are two advantages here:

- `num` is scoped inside the loop, when before it was bleeding into whatever scope followed the `while`. Restricting variables to the minimum possible scope is a good rule of thumb, because it minimizes the amount of variables to think about at any given point.
- The range over which your program will operate is now summarized in a single place: you can see the bounds (1 to 100) and the step (1) inside the `for`. That kind of ranges is pretty well balanced to be read and memorized quickly before reading the body of the loop. For example, if you now wanted to only check odd numbers, it would be immediately clear from reading the `num += 2` in the `for` header, rather than stumbling upon it at the very end of the loop's body.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That really helped clarify the benefits of using a for loop.  Being new to coding I am still trying to understand which approach works best for a particular problem.